# What's under the hood of numpy's 'mean' function such that it works faster than built in python methods?

Tags: python, numpy

I've been exploring the performance differences between numpy functions and the normal built-in functions of Python, and I want to know how numpy functions are so optimized such that there's almost a 100x speed up.
Below is some code that I wrote to highlight the execution time differences between  **numpy mean()**  and manual calculation of mean using  **sum()** and **len()**

```
import numpy as np
import time

n = 10**7
a = np.random.randn(n)
start = time.perf_counter()
mean = sum(a)/len(a)
seconds1 = time.perf_counter()-start

start = time.perf_counter()
mean = np.mean(a)
seconds2 = time.perf_counter()-start

print("First method takes time {:.3f}s".format(seconds1))

print("Second method takes time {:.3f}s".format(seconds2))
```

**Output:-** 

*First method takes 1.687s

Second method takes 0.013s*

Comment: numpy works fast because it has compiled C and C++ code under the hood

Comment: Welcome to the magic of numpy :)  FYI, this is true of nearly all the numpy api (as well as spicy, and pandas for the most part). Its makes use of compiled binaries as well as SIMD operations.  IMO it's an unbeatable mix of performance and friendly dev. experience

Comment: Test `a.sum()/a.shape[0]`

Comment: @hpaulj I get same time of execution with this method! Wow! So built-in python functions can also compete with numpy, interesting!

Comment: Actually, `a.sum()` is a `numpy`.  Here `sum` is a method of the `a` array object.  Nearly equivalent is `np.sum(a)`.

Comment: @hpaulj Got it. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Make a numpy array:

```
In [130]: a=np.arange(10000)
```

Apply the `numpy` sum function:

```
In [131]: timeit np.sum(a)
16.2 µs ± 22.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`mean` is a bit slower, since it has to divide by the shape (and may do a few other tests):

```
In [132]: timeit np.mean(a)
34.9 µs ± 198 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`np.sum` actually delegates the action to the `sum` method of the array, so using that directly is a bit faster:

```
In [133]: timeit a.sum()
13.3 µs ± 25.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Python `sum` isn't a bad function, but it iterates over its argument.  Iterating (in Python code) on an array is slow:

```
In [134]: timeit sum(a)
1.16 ms ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Converting the array to a list first saves time:

```
In [135]: timeit sum(a.tolist())
369 µs ± 7.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Better yet if we just time the list operation:

```
In [136]: %%timeit alist=a.tolist()
     ...: sum(alist)
57.2 µs ± 294 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

When working with numpy arrays, it is best to use its own methods (or numpy functions).  Generally when using Python functions, it is better to use lists.

Using a numpy function on a list is slow, because it has to first convert the list to an array:

```
In [137]: %%timeit alist=a.tolist()
     ...: np.sum(alist)
795 µs ± 28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```